# SharePoint 2010 Alerts

Tags: list-view, alert

I have a list in SharePoint 2010 with 2 views, one of them use a [Me] filter where a user can only see the items created for him, and the other view have all items with any filter. 
My problem is if a user set an alert on the filtered view they receive a email every time a item is created even if they don't have access to him.
How can I only allow alerts for items that appear on the filtered view ?
And I can't user SharePoint Designer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If users only need to see items they have created - then use the advanced list configuration and set item read and create/edit access that were "created by the user"

- Open your list
- In the ribbon go to settings
- Click on Advanced Find the Item
- Permission part of the page and set accordingly.

Admins, owners or anyone with the 'Cancel Checkout' permission can see all items, so you can still use the [Me] filter to trim the list for these individuals (but they will still get all alerts on the list).

The other alternatives are a bit more complicated as you have to set item level security, and use multiple lists with workflows (which require at least SharePoint designer) to move data around.